Equivalence of $\underline{\mathbf{Set}}^{\underline G}$ and $G$-$\underline{\mathbf{Set}}$
Let $G$ be a group. Let $\underline{\mathbf{Set}}^{\underline G}$ be the category of functors $\underline G \rightarrow \underline{\mathbf{Set}}$ with natural transformations as morphisms. $(\underline G$ is the category associated to $G.)$
I need to show that $\underline{\mathbf{Set}}^{\underline G}$ and $G$-$\underline{\mathbf{Set}}$ are equivalent categories, but I honestly have problems visualizing these categories, which makes it hard to even imagine the kind of functors I want to define. I would be very grateful if someone could give me even a hint in the right direction!

$\underline{G}$ is a one-object category, so a functor $\underline{G} \to \mathbf{Set}$ picks out a set $X$ and, for every element of $G$, an endomorphism $X \to X$. Since every morphism in $\underline{G}$ is invertible, these endomorphisms have to be automorphisms, and furthermore the assignment respects $G$'s group structure, so this is exactly equivalent to the data of a $G$-set.
